# How can I customize response propeties and JWT Token payload properties to lowerCamelCase

Tags: java, spring, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

success response from oauth 2.0

```
"access_token": "xxxx",
"expires_in": 123456,
"scope": "read write"
```

to lowerCamelCase

```
"accessToken": "xxxx",
"expiresIn": 123456,
"scope": "read write"
```

and jwt payload properties

```
{
  "user_name": "xxxxx",
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "exp": 1567481992,
  "authorities": [
    "XXX"
  ],
  "jti": "xxxxxx",
  "client_id": "xxxxxx"
}
```

to lowerCamelCase

```
{
  "userName": "xxxxx",
  "scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
  ],
  "exp": 1567481992,
  "authorities": [
    "XXX"
  ],
  "jti": "xxxxxx",
  "clientId": "xxxxxx"
}
```

I try to using jackson-property-naming-strategy: LOWER_CAMEL_CASE but it's not work for me.

Comment: How did you configure that lower-case strategy, using `application.properties`? If yes, are you using object-mapper provided by Spring, or just create a new object manually?

Comment: @MaxFarsikov I use default from framework.

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like spring has configured it's Jackson object-mapper bean, but you are using different one, probably created by rest-template or another library. Could you please show a code how do you call that service and how it is parsed

Comment: @MaxFarsikov I call that service from default endpoint of oauth2 /oauth/token